# Should you post link to similar question as comment?

Tags: discussion

Here's my predicament!

Lets say we have new Question `QuestionNew` with no answers, fresh off the press

I went to answer the question and while researching I found another question call it `QuestionSimilar` on SO that's already been answered with more than 1 answers

Note that `QuestionNew` is not a duplicate but the user will get good idea on how to solve the question by reading through the `QuestionSimilars` answers and discussions

I posted a link to `QuestionSimilar` in the comment of `QuestionNew`

So My Question is

Does SO change the links overtime?
 i.e. If I come back to `QuestionNew` after 10 years will the link in the comment still be working?

What should be the recommended/suggested action in this case?

Comment: Doesn't the same hold for posts and not just comments? Also, why would things change in terms of the links "10 years from now"?

Comment: We encounter the broken links all the time, typical example would be if the original question is deleted!

Comment: Well yes, if the question is deleted, then it's not there anymore (or perhaps just invisible to specific users). That's really not a broken link...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329/what-are-five-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-language#282342

Comment: It is good that you show people you did research. However, you can summarized the linked question (and answers) in your question body and not worrying about broken link anymore.

Comment: "Note that QuestionNew is not a duplicate but the user will get good idea on how to solve the question by reading through the QuestionSimilars answers and discussions" That sounds very much like they are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I'll definitely say yes.

***As a comment or as an answer (depend of the context)...

...and if you find a broken one, Flag'it! mods can't be everywhere.***

I see three scenarios where this *dilema* can show up:

1. Duplicate

   - Easy one, in a `Comment` format, write down the `duplicate answer link`
   - Add small brief so the user know what that link is for.
   - And Flag the question to let the Moderators know it's a duplicate one.
     _
2. Similar/Related <sup>(you **don't have** OP answer)</sup>

   - If the external reference you find on SO is similar to OP question, and can help to find out what's going on and/or point him on the right direction...
   - Then I will post this as a `Comment`, you'r actually not answer the question, but helping to find out with other user answer/comments.
     _
3. Similar/Related <sup>(you do **have or know** OP answer)</sup>

   - If the external reference can help to solve the question and you know how to modify to fit question needs, can provide examples or references to do it...
   - Then this will definitely goes as an `Answer`.
   - Include in your answer the external link as reference or any other source you think could be helpfull.
     _

Now, for the **original worry about broken links...**
<sup>(in comments or in answers doesn't matters, if it's broken it's broken)</sup>
I will always try to:

1. Left a comment to the author to let him know (and hopefully, fix) the broken link.
2. If I know the good one, included in my comment for further readers.
3. Flag the comment, we have the posibility to flag answers and comments for this, just select the rigth choice (`obsolete` in this case) and give the Mod's the chance to look it up.

Comment: What if the answer linked to is an answer to OP's question, but the question is very different? As in if you word for word typed out the answer, it would be correct, but it is in no way a duplicate question.

Comment: @ThomasBoby
The same explanation can solve many disparate questions. According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217401), it might be appropriate to mark as a duplicate. But for very-frequent shared answers, would that be a [wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740)?
For example, the memory management of the OS can cause many behaviors. [I thought it was SQL Server, but I was merely paged](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212578/140226) (along with some hidden memory management details specific to SQL Server), so I got a wiki answer.