# Is an answer that links to another answer valid as an answer, or should it be a comment?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

A user has added an answer to this question which links to another answer for a similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632974/89211

Am I correct in my assessment that it should be moved to a comment? The author of the answer notes that it is a complement to the other answer on the same question.

Should I downvote it? or Should I flag it? If flag, which flag?

I guess this is related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265693/89211

Comment: Downvote and flag it as NAA.

Comment: I'd flag it as VLQ and downvote (*"If you think so, down vote it :)"*)

Comment: It is a valid answer.  It is not a *desirable* answer, most SO users demand that Q+A is canonical.  With 10 million of them on the books, that's a bit hard to justify, perhaps :)  Not having enough rep to vote a question as duplicate is not otherwise a valid reason to post such an answer.

Comment: It's deleted now because, as everyone else has said, it wasn't a real answer (technically an answer, but VLQ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [link-only answer rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) applies to every case where the answer is just a link, regardless of where the link is to. The rule goes like this: leave the link text, but remove the fact that it is a link. Is *that* an answer? If it isn't, neither is the original.

Applying the rule in this case gives us this:

> If you want to replicate the circle boarder expanding/shrinking as you
>   scroll down your list, pls take a look at this answer!

Is that an answer? No it isn't, so neither was the original.

Just because it links to another SO post does not make it anything other than a link-only answer. The same reasoning applies: SO posts can be deleted, and might not directly answer the question.

The only thing that possibly changes is what the answerer should do instead of posting a link-only answer:

- If the linked answer contains an appropriate solution, but it might not be directly apparent that it is a solution to this question, then in addition to the link, relevant parts should be quoted and the answer should give whatever extra context is needed. This is exactly the same as if the link is to a random website.
- If the answer *clearly* applies - because any answer to the linked question would equally answer this one - then they shouldn't post an answer, but VTC or flag as dup. This is different to if the link is to somewhere other than SO (because we can't dup against other sites).

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not a valid answer, it should have been a comment. It just says: "take a look at this", but holds no constructive information to help to OP with his actual problem. It's merely a hint where he can get more information, but that in itself is not an answer.

So, I would suggest to downvote it and flag it as "Not an answer".