# Is it permissible to comment links to related, unsolved questions whose solution likely advances both?

Tags: discussion, comments

To imagine some benefits:

1. If there is a solution to my question with subtle keyword differences, the problem might be linked through a comment.
2. If it has been a while since the question has seen activity, perhaps OP has figured it out and the comment's notification will prompt an answer.
3. As well, if a question is answered, involved parties might actively share it with other related questions brought to their attention.
4. Finally, it will consolidate knowledge by improving the links between relevant information in general.

**But what bad comes from bumping?**

Comment: Related: [Should you post links to similar questions as comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261811/should-you-post-link-to-similar-question-as-comment). This question isn't quite what you're interested in because you're looking for cases when both questions are unsolved and this other question is linking unsolved questions to related solved questions, but the discussion it produced can be beneficial to the topic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any obvious downsides of such comments and definitely such comments are not against site's rules (assuming questions are actually materially different).

Bumping other similar questions with comment is welcome as we want questions useful to multiple people to be answered and you have good reason to believe such question is useful to you (making it at least 2 people interested in question). Note that you should be careful to not to over-promote your own question and only link back when you expect future visitors may get value of answers to your question. I'd definitely be concerned if I'd feel need to put "I have similar q {link}" comments to more than couple posts.

Ideally if you are author of the question you would link such other questions from the post with "similar, differs in ... and no answer" remarks.

Note that if question you are about to ask already  exists on the site without an answer then proper approach is to put a bounty on existing one and not ask new one. If you anyway go ahead and ask a new duplicate post probably would not get warm reception. Linking to unanswered duplicate will likely cause question to be closed as "unclear what you are asking" (as you should not be asking duplicate), not linking to duplicate likely cause down votes due to "no research shown".

One additional benefit is new question may be expanded to include old once and all suggested "similar, no answer" questions closed as duplicate when first one answered.

Comment: Indeed one must avoid warrant-less promotion of their own question, but I am assuming the commentor is following the duplicate questions rule. What I am finding happening is that I have question X and could not find an answer to it, but found questions Y and Z that seem quite similar (also unanswered), so I am hoping to draw attention since I perceive the answer to one will further the answer to the others.